# How to host 2 AngularJS app in 1 instance of Heroku?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, restify

I have an API coded in Nodejs and an AngularJS app statically served by the same server.

I need to host another AngularJS app which should be served by the same server.

How can I do that? Can Restify or Express serve 2 static apps?

I used

```
server.get(/\/shared\/?.*/, restify.serveStatic({
  directory: __dirname + '/shared/.build',
  default: 'index.html'
}));
```

doesn't work if I write

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/shared
```

Comment: It depends on how exactly you want to serve them. It would be relatively simple to serve the two apps from the same domain under two separate folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
app.use('/app1', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/app1/.build')))
app.use('/app2', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/app2/.build')))
```

Comment: Yes, it is working. I think the problem is about Restify's serveStatic plugin.